# data from python list

Tags: python-3.x

How does itertools.combination works to get all combinations of data
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using this function from python3 docs:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(permutations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Comment: this solution fails to provide the reversed order elements like 'ba'

Comment: oh.. just replace combinations with itertools.permutations